# Multiple web services sharing the same classes

Tags: c#, java, web-services

I have 2 web services, one written in java and the other in c#.  The java web service is the main web service and the .net web service is a backup, so the .net service basically just mirrors the java service.

The problem is that when i generate my client code using wsdl.exe /sharetypes none of the types are shared.  This leaves me with something like this

AClass,
AClass1

SecondClass,
SecondClass1

I want my client to basically use these 2 web services interchangeably.  If i cant connect to the java service i want to connect to the .net service and use it the exact same way, but if the types are not the same i cannot achieve this.

BTW the client must be written in .net 2.0

Thanks ahead for any help!

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you generate the code against one service and then plug in the URL for the other service?  Does it successfully use the code from the first one?  If so, can you just make the URL be a couple of config values to swap out if one of the services is down?

Comment: +1: Only generate one set of client-side bindings. If these bindings don't allow full operation against both web services then you need to adjust the web services themselves so that they match exactly.

Comment: Yes im running into problems with this.  The java service has more operations than the .net service so i have to generate my bindings off of the java service.